# IE 9 support for Base64 image encoding

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Does IE 9 support Base64 image encoding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean base64 encode data:uri ? IE8 supports it with limitations - the data can only be max 32K. So, IE9 would definitely support it.

See the [wikiepedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) on this subject.

Comment: are you sure that ie9 will support base64 image encoding?

Comment: Pretty sure. I am confident they won't go back on a feature that was implemented in IE8, and that all the other browsers already support without restriction.

Answer (score 1):

As IE 9 is not released yet (just beta version) we cannot strongly say **Yes** but if nothing changes until its release date, it will support it.

Comment: Update: IE9 has been released and supports base64 encoding without the 32kb limit that was imposed upon ie8.